# Mini JQuery slider scrolls whole page, when it moved up. How to stop it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an up-down mini(col-md-4) JQuery slider. When the navigation of the browser is on the slider, the whole page also scrolls up by the slider sliding up.

Is there a way to make it independent? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Share plugin link..

Comment: I am using this slider :  http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-News-Ticker-Plugin-with-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-News-Box/